# Http post request for token based authentication

Tags: http, angular, ionic2

This is my first application in angular 2 and I am doing jwt authentication for my mobile application,i have problem with HTTP post and i already checked my post Url in Postman it works fine and i got token also. but when i post from client side i got an error. Please get me out.

login.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="login()" #loginForm="ngForm">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="email_border">
            <ion-label class="labelstyle"> <ion-icon class="icon" color="dark" ios="ios-person" md="md-person"></ion-icon></ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
          <div style="font-size:0;height:6px;"></div>
        <ion-item class="email_border">
          <ion-label class="labelstyle"> <ion-icon class="icon" color="dark" ios="ios-unlock" md="md-unlock"></ion-icon></ion-label>
          <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Kennwort" [(ngModel)]="Kennwort" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
      <button icon-left ion-button block type="submit" class="log" [disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid">
        <ion-icon style="font-size: 30px" ios="ios-key" md="md-key"></ion-icon> Login </button>
</form>
<button ion-button block clear (click)="register()" class="register"> Register For Free Trail </button>
<button ion-button block clear (click)="resetPwd()" class="fpasswd"> Forgot Password </button>
```

login.ts

```
login(name,Kennwort) {
this.auth.loginuser(name,Kennwort).subscribe((result) => {
  if (result) {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
  }
});
```

}

authservice.ts

```
loginuser(name:string, Kennwort:string):Observable<boolean> {
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this.http.post('node.futures-services.com:9000/api/authenticate/', JSON.stringify({ name:name, Kennwort:Kennwort }), { headers:headers })
.map(res => res.json()).map((res) => {
    if (res.success) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
      this.loggedIn = true;
    }
    return res.success;
  }).catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
```

}

error look like this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYWFz.png)

Comment: you need to add the error to the question

Comment: looks like a cors issue.. it only affects you in `ionic serve` and wont matter in device.. setup a proxy as in this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41778351/4826457)

Comment: I just check it with my mobile device when i click on login button it shows nothing no event occurs. Is it body parse user details properly and is it any  problem with data binding.

Comment: In your login.ts, `this.auth.loginuser(name,Kennwort).subscribe((result) => {
  if (result) {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
  }
},error=>{});` log the error and check

Comment: no change it shows new error like  More tasks executed then were scheduled. nothing shows in mobile. anyway thank you suraj for your effort.